# Como dejar activo el background-color al pulsar un boton con css

Tags: html5, css3

> Tengo 2 botones en un formulario, si pulso sobre 1 dibujo su fondo de un color y con el otro igual, pero al pinchar en un input, se me va el color del boton seleccionado.Lo que necesito es que siga el fondo del boton activo hasta que le de al submit Codigo css:

```
form button:hover{
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color:#00aae4;
   color: #fbfcfc;
}
form button:focus, form button:active{
     background-color:#00aae4;
     color: #fbfcfc;
}
```

> Estoy tratando de hacerlo con JQuery, pero no funciona, alguien me puede explicar, aqui va codigo:

```
$(function() {
$("#form").on('click', 'button', function(e) {
    var id=this.id;
    var btn = document.getElementById(id);
    if(btn==="btnUsuario"){
        btn.style.backgroundColor="#00aae4";
        btn.style.color="#fbfcfc";
    }else{
        btn.style.backgroundColor="transparent";
        btn.style.color="#00aae4";
    }
    if(btn==="btnGrupo"){
        btn.style.backgroundColor="#00aae4";
        btn.style.color="#fbfcfc";
    }else{
        btn.style.backgroundColor="transparent";
        btn.style.color="#00aae4";
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Necesitas hacerlo con javascript, no vale sólo CSS, usando jQuery o similar para añadir una clase CSS al hace click sobre el botón

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> LA SOLUCIÓN AL PROBLEMA:

```
function choice(){
var btnUsuario = document.getElementById("btnUsuario");
var btnGrupo = document.getElementById("btnGrupo");
var tipo = document.getElementById("tipo");

//Aqui controlo el color del fondo dependiendo que opcion escogio
btnUsuario.onclick = function(e){
      tipo.value =  this.value;
      btnUsuario.style.backgroundColor="#00aae4";
      btnUsuario.style.color="#fbfcfc";
      btnGrupo.style.backgroundColor="transparent";
      btnGrupo.style.color="#00aae4";
      console.log(tipo);
 }

btnGrupo.onclick = function(e){
      tipo.value =  this.value;
      btnGrupo.style.backgroundColor="#00aae4";
      btnGrupo.style.color="#fbfcfc";
      btnUsuario.style.backgroundColor="transparent";
      btnUsuario.style.color="#00aae4";
      console.log(tipo);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Edit: El autor del post en resumidas cuentas necesita hacer que 2 botones en este caso cambien de color como si fuese un checkbox sin usar jQuery, en el código acontinuación podrán encontrar la respuesta con vanilla JavaScript.

```js
var boton1 = document.getElementById("boton1");
var boton2 = document.getElementById("boton2");

document.getElementById('boton1').addEventListener("click", function(){
  
   if(boton2.classList.contains("active")){
      boton2.classList.remove("active");
   }
  
   if(!boton1.classList.contains("active")){
      boton1.classList.toggle("active");
   }
  
});

document.getElementById('boton2').addEventListener("click", function(){
  
   if(boton1.classList.contains("active")){
      boton1.classList.remove("active");
   }
   
   if(!boton2.classList.contains("active")){
      boton2.classList.toggle("active");
   }
  
});
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container p-5 bg-info">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="boton1" class="btn btn-primary toggle">Boton 1</button>
    <button type="submit" id="boton2" class="btn btn-primary toggle">Boton 2</button>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/BrayamValero/pen/YzXEpMp

Comment: Tengo 2 botones, con esto estoy intentando que se me quede un boton con el fondo de color, si pulso sobre uno le coloreo el fondo y si pulso el otro  se colorea el otro, en resumen que solo puede haber 1 boton con fondo de color. En plan solo 1 activo de los 2. Como si de un radiobutton se tratase

Comment: Ya está actualizado, revisa el código de nuevo. Solo tenías que usar un toggle y verificar que el otro botón tuviese o no la clase "active".

Comment: Mil disculpas, había subido el pen que no era, ya está actualizado nuevamente.

Comment: Considera agregar aquí tu código pues las respuestas que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, lo editaré.

Comment: Miguel igual y le falta tal vez una explicación pero de que si califica como respuesta eso sin duda